Laplace transform of $\sqrt{t(t+a)}/(t+b)$
I am looking for results as the integration of
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{\sqrt{t}\,\sqrt{t + a}}{t + b}\,\exp\left(-st\right)\,{\rm d}t
$$
where $a$, $b$, $s$ are positive constants.
Can it be integrated out or represented by some other functions such as $\Gamma$ function $?$. Thanks.

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please edit the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

It is a Kummer function for $a=b$. Possibly a $_1F_1$ confluent function in the general case. Have a look in Abramovitz and Stegun.

Thanks a lot for your information. I had tried to find some clues from the book you mentioned or other materials, but no thought about it was obtained.

With $f(t,a,b)=\frac{\sqrt{t (t+a)}}{t+b}$ and $a=b$:
$$\int_0^{\infty } f(t,a,a) \exp (-s t) \, dt=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } U\left(\frac{1}{2},0,a s\right)}{2 s}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \exp \left(\frac{a s}{2}\right) W_{-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}}(a s)}{2 s}$$
With $U(a,b,z)$ the Tricomi confluent hypergeometric function.
$W_{k,m}(z)$ is the Whittaker function.
